# User specific cache in Dotnetnuke

Tags: session, caching, dotnetnuke

**How can i use user specific cache in Dotnetnuke instead of session?**
Using session in dotnetnuke causes many instabilities in a custom dnn module, for example when session timeout reaches, cache timeout is not reached yet so it causes that session variables clear before dnn user logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is going to really depend on exactly what you are trying to store.  If it is truly "user specific" you could use the Personalization functionality within DNN - http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/134603/module-settings-and-personalization-easily-store-data-for-your-dotnetnuke-module

The general solution here though is not a DNN specific solution, but one that would be an issue regardless of the framework, so any solution you find will work.

DNN does not have a user specific cache, and I strongly recommend against trying to circumvent this by using DNN's cache for user specific items, this can have a dramatic impact on system stability and performance.